# Execute SOQL query from Windows batch file script

Tags: soql

Can we execute SOQL query from Windows batch script file(.bat) and loop through the records?

Comment: Basically Salesforce provides SOAP and Rest API's which you can consume in your code to fetch the appropriate records. Question would be can you use it in your windows bat script.

Comment: An example please?

Comment: Here are links to [SOAP](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_quickstart_intro.htm) and [Rest](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/intro_what_is_rest_api.htm) API's

Comment: Batch files are not powerful enough by themselves to do any real data processing. You're going to want to use something like Python, Perl, Ruby, JavaScript, PowerShell, PHP, etc. The batch file itself would only call the scripting language you specify.

Comment: Thanks all..so we can execute SOQL using the scripting langauge and this scripting lauguage can we called from batch script?

Answer (score 2):

To your specific question, the Salesforce Data Loader can be automated from the command line (or PowerShell) to extract records based on a SOQL query. See [Data Loader Command-Line Operations](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.dataLoader.meta/dataLoader/loader_operations.htm)

Another option is the [Command-line Interface for Force.com](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/developer-relations/2013/11/announcing-the-command-line-interface-for-force-com.html).

Once you have the data [PowerShell](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11885405/54026) or the [Command Line](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22499857/54026) can iterate over it. As per the comments, choosing the appropriate tool will depend on what you are going to do with the data once it is extracted.